# Find a given file recursively inside a directory

Tags: python-3.6

Find a given file recursively inside a dir. The code I tried is not showing any output, though I have a file C:\Users\anaveed\test\hoax\a.txt

Below the code

```
import glob
import os

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\anaveed\test')
for f in glob.iglob('a.txt', recursive=True):
    print(f)
```

No output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need.

```
import glob

for f in glob.iglob(r'C:\Users\anaveed\test\**\a.txt', recursive=True):
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it:

```py
import os

path = r'C:\Users\anaveed\test'
filename = 'a.txt'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name == filename:
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

A couple of comments:

1. you do not need to use `glob` if you are not specifying wildcards, just use `os.walk()`
2. you do not need to move to a specific path to look for files therein, just save the path into a variable.
3. it would be even better to wrap this into a function (perhaps using a list comprehension).
4. the `glob` solution is typically faster.